# Reactjs onScroll event not responding

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been answered alot of times but my challenge is peculiar,as I have tried all the answers here but no luck still.
here is my code

```
export default class scrollLogic extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            scroll:false
        };
        this.scrollDetector=this.scrollDetector.bind(this)
    }

    scrollDetector(ev) {
        console.log("Scrolling!");
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        list.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollDetector);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        list.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollDetector);
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div ref="list" className="header-holder"></div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the onScroll event should only be used with containers that itself has a scrollbar, so using `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollDetector)` instead solved the problem. As it listens to a scroll of the window itself and not the div.

so i have formatted my code to look like this

```
export default class scrollLogic extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            scroll:false
        };
        this.scrollDetector=this.scrollDetector.bind(this)
    }

    scrollDetector() {

        this.setState({
                scroll:true
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollDetector);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollDetector);
    }
render() {
        return (
            (this.state.scroll)? <HeaderMin/>:<HeaderMax/>
)
}
}
```

I hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are using `componentDidMount` method which is called after the component has rendered. Try using `componentWillMount` rather than using `componentDidMount`.